# django - simple equation

Tags: django, math, django-models

why does model.diff return 18446744073709551615 in template, when model is like this and model.pos is 0 and model.neg is 1?:

```
class Kaart(models.Model):
    neg = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    pos = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    def diff(self):
        return self.pos - self.neg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting underflow, where `self.pos - self.neg` should give `-1`, but you have a positive field, so it wraps around and you get `0 - 1 = 18446744073709551615`, the largest positive number representable by PositiveIntegerField.

For your reference, `18446744073709551615 = 2**64 - 1`, which means that PositiveIntegerField stores 64-bit values.

Comment: Actually, 18446744073709551615 is === 2^64-1.

Comment: allright, but why does'nt x = self.pos - self.neg work any different? I mean, do i have to change field type just so the equation would work? thats kinda stupid, aint it, as x has not been described as variable?

Comment: Thanks for responses everybody. It seems that the best thing to do was to change field type from PositiveIntegerField to IntegerField

Answer (score 0):

Peter's probably right. Try:

```
def diff(self):
    return int(self.pos) - int(self.neg)
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Before posting i did try this:
 def diff(self):
  x = int(self.pos) - int(self.neg)
  return x

Which gives exactly the same result.